# getting column names and its aliases print from a sql query in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a compound SQL query. I need to extract only the column names and its aliases. Those names should be printed side by side corresponding to each column names.
Can I do the above problem without connecting to the database?

Query is:

```
SELECT ISNULL(DISTINCT COALESCE(ActivityName, 'BLANK'), 'NULLVALUE') AS ActName, ActivityPK Primary, ActCode Code, StartDt as ‘Start Date’,
(SELECT ECODE FROM ActBCodes WHERE act.ActBCode_FK=BCodePK) ECode FROM TBL_TMX_Activity act
```

output should be

```
ISNULL(DISTINCT COALESCE(ActivityName, 'BLANK'), 'NULLVALUE')  ActName

ActivityPK     Primary   

ActCode      Code        

StartDt       StartDate     

(SELECT ECODE FROM ActBCodes WHERE act.ActBCode_FK=BCodePK)       ECode
```

Comment: i think i mentioned it in the question.anyways the query is :  SELECT ISNULL(DISTINCT COALESCE(ActivityName, 'BLANK'), 'NULLVALUE') AS ActName, ActivityPK Primary, ActCode Code, StartDt as ‘Start Date’,
(SELECT ECODE FROM ActBCodes WHERE act.ActBCode_FK=BCodePK) ECode FROM TBL_TMX_Activity act

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could write your own SQL parser that splits different parts of the SQL up. I warn you, this may get an exhausting task.

You can use ANTLR, which is a parser/lexer tool. It is build to recognize 'languages', like SQL. As you can see [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4), there are some SQL grammars already. You can use that to parse your SQL and get the desired results.

A solution that might be easier to write for you but more error-prone is using regular expressions. If you want to have it reliable, I would recommend ANTLR.

Comment: yup,I tried to write my own sql parser but it will work only for this query not a generic one.So I like to know is there any sql query that can fetch these details if we do this by connecting to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace columm_names
{
    public class column
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            string text = "SELECT ISNULL(DISTINCT COALESCE(ActivityName, 'BLANK'), 'NULLVALUE') AS ActName, ActivityPK Primary, ActCode Code, StartDt as ‘Start Date’, (SELECT ECODE FROM ActBCodes WHERE act.ActBCode_FK=BCodePK) ECode FROM TBL_TMX_Activity act";
            string s1,s2,text2;
            string[] last_str,str;
            int first = text.IndexOf("SELECT") + "SELECT".Length;
            int last = text.IndexOf("AS");
            int count=0;
            int index=0;
            int x = 1;int i = 0;
            char[] seperators = { ' ' };

            List<string> column_name = new List<string>();
            List<string> alias = new List<string>();

            while (text.Length!=0 && last >0)
            {
                text2 = sub_string(first,last,text);
                if (x == 1)
                {
                    column_name.Add(text2);
                    index = text.IndexOf(text2) + text2.Length+2;text = text.Remove(0, index); 
                    index = text.IndexOf(",");
                    text2 = text.Substring(0, index);
                    alias.Add(text2); x = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (text2.IndexOf("as") > 0)
                    {
                        s1 = sub_string(first,text.IndexOf("as"),text); 
                        column_name.Add(s1);
                        s2 = sub_string (text.IndexOf ("as") + 3, text.IndexOf (","), text);
                        alias.Add(s2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        str = text2.Split(seperators); 
                        column_name.Add(str[0]);
                        alias.Add(str[1]);
                    }
                }
                index = text.IndexOf(text2) + text2.Length + 1;text = text.Remove(0, index);
                first =1;
                last = text.IndexOf(",");

                if (last < 0) 
                { 
                    last_str = text.Split(seperators);
                    text2="";
                    while(i<last_str.Length)
                    {
                        if(count == 2){break;}
                        else {if(last_str[i]=="FROM"){count++;index =i;}}
                        i++;
                    }

                    for(i=0;i<index-1;i++){text2+=" "+last_str[i];}
                    column_name.Add(text2);
                    alias.Add(last_str[index-1]);break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine ("Column Names"); display (column_name);
            Console.WriteLine("\n Alias");display (alias);
        }

        static string sub_string(int x,int y,string z)
        {
            string r =z.Substring(x, y-x);
            return r;
        }

        static void display(List<string> lst)
        {   string[] arr = lst.ToArray();
            foreach(string s in arr){Console.WriteLine (s);Console.ReadLine ();}
        }
    }

}
```